# OLS and GLS distribution for $b|X$

Tags: least-squares, generalized-least-squares

Does anyone now the distribution for $b|X$ for OLS and GLS?

\begin{aligned}
b^{OLS} &= (X'X)^{-1}X'y \\
b^{GLS} &= (X'\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X'\Omega^{-1}y
\end{aligned}

Comment: It depends on what you assume about $y.$  Are you supposing, for instance, that it is multivariate Normal?